# Vertx JS Eventbus connection being created then closing

Tags: javascript, websocket, proxy, vert.x

**Background:** using *Vertx 3.3.3 Core* and *Web* on Java side as a server, using *vertx-web-3.3.3-client.js* as the client with *sockjsclient1.1.2.js*

**Issue:** I am successfully making a connection to the eventbus from the client when on my local machine or LAN. When I go through a proxy, the wss eventbus connection is being blocked (in Firefox I see "*Firefox can't establish a connection to "wss://...*"; in Chromium I see "*WebSocket connection to wss://... failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400*", then I see "*https ://.../eventbus/.../xhr_send?t=... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status code of 500*"). However, the *onopen* fires and I receive some data (connection downgraded to an accepted protocol?). Immediately after this, *onclose* fires and I have lost connection. I know that I am successfully reaching the Java vertx server because my static web and API calls are working.

**Questions:** I have looked through the Vertx and SockJS documentation extensively. Is there:

1. Documentation on how vertx tries different transport protocols in the JS Eventbus connection?
2. An example of JS Vertx Eventbus working through a business proxy?
3. Another way to implement the Eventbus connection, perhaps specifying the SockJS protocol(s) to try/use? (I am trying the simplest way to create an eventbus connection, as shown in many places in documentation)
4. Something I need to do on the Java side of the SockJS/Eventbus setup?

**Thanks in advance for any advice/help!**

**EDIT 1:** Adding the following code for both Java server and JavaScript web client sides. The web side is very basic (and what is failing). The Java side is using Spring for dependency injection and application config, has an Eventbus connection, one API call, and serves static web content.

The API call from client to server works, and the server sources the web contents correctly, so accessing the tool is working. However, the proxy is causing wss to fail (as expected) but the downgrade to xhr-streaming is failing (I think)

Javascript:

```
var EB;
var URL;
var APICall = "api/eventbus/publish/";
var IncomingAddress = "heartbeat-test";
var OutgoingAddress = "client-test";

function createConnection(){
    URL = $("#serveraddressinput").val(); //Getting url from html text box
    console.log("Creating Eventbus connection at " + URL + "eventbus"); //Eventbus address is '<link>/eventbus'
    EB = new EventBus(URL + "eventbus");

    testAPICall();

    EB.onopen = function(){
        console.log("Eventbus connection successfully made at " + URL + "eventbus");
        console.log("Registering Eventbus handler for messages at " + IncomingAddress);

        EB.registerHandler(IncomingAddress, function(error, message){
            console.log("Received Eventbus message " + JSON.stringify(message));
    };

    EB.onclose = function(){
        console.log("Eventbus connection at " + URL + " has been lost");
        URL = "";
    };
}

function testAPICall(){
    var link = URL + APICall + "heartbeat-test";
    console.log("Testing API call to " + link);
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"testFromClient": "Test message sent from Client via API Call"}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            console.log("API Call Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log("API Call ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(request) + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

function sendTestMessage(){
    console.log("Sending test message to address " + OutgoingAddress);
    EB.send(OutgoingAddress, "Testing 1, 2, 3...");
}
```

Java:

```
...

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.net.JksOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeEvent;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeEventType;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.PermittedOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandler;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyTestVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTestVerticle.class);

    final Level ACCESS = Level.forName("ACCESS", 450);

    private boolean started;

    private int port;

    @Value("${webserver.testpath.enabled}")
    private boolean testPathEnabled;

    @Value("${webserver.urlpath.test}")
    private String testUrlPath;

    @Value("${webserver.filepath.test}")
    private String testFilePath;

    @Value("${webserver.caching.enabled}")
    private boolean cachingEnabled;

    @Value("${webserver.ssl.enabled}")
    private boolean sslEnabled;

    private BridgeOptions bridgeOptions;

    private SockJSHandler sockJsHandler;

    private Router router;

    private JksOptions sslKeyStoreOptions;

    private JksOptions sslTrustStoreOptions;

    public MyTestVerticle() {
        this.started = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {
        log.info("start() -- starting Vertx Verticle with eventbus, API handler, and static file handler");

        // grab the router
        router = getRouter();

        // enable CORS for the router 
        CorsHandler corsHandler = CorsHandler.create("*");  //Wildcard(*) not allowed if allowCredentials is true
        corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
        corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        corsHandler.allowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        corsHandler.allowCredentials(false);
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method");
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
        corsHandler.allowedHeader("Content-Type");

        // enable handling of body
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        router.route().handler(corsHandler);
        router.route().handler(this::handleAccessLogging);

        // publish a payload to provided eventbus destination
        router.post("/api/eventbus/publish/:destination").handler(this::publish);

        // open up all for outbound and inbound traffic
        bridgeOptions = new BridgeOptions();
        bridgeOptions.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
        bridgeOptions.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
//        sockJsHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(bridgeOptions);   
         sockJsHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx);
         sockJsHandler.bridge(bridgeOptions, be -> {
            try {
                if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CREATED) {
                    handleSocketOpenEvent(be);
                }
                else if(be.type() ==BridgeEventType.REGISTER) {
                    handleRegisterEvent(be);
                }
                else if(be.type() ==BridgeEventType.UNREGISTER) {
                    handleUnregisterEvent(be);
                }
                else if(be.type() ==BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CLOSED) {
                    handleSocketCloseEvent(be);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                be.complete(true);
            }
        });
        router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(sockJsHandler);

        if(testPathEnabled){
            router.route("/" + testUrlPath + "/*").handler(StaticHandler.create(testFilePath).setCachingEnabled(cachingEnabled));
        }

        // create periodic task, pushing all current EventBusRegistrations
        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, handler -> {
            JsonObject obj =new JsonObject();
            obj.put("testMessage", "Periodic test message from server...");
            vertx.eventBus().publish("heartbeat-test", Json.encodePrettily(obj));
        });

        EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
        eb.consumer("client-test", message -> {
            log.info("Received message from client: " + Json.encodePrettily(message.body()) + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        });

        HttpServerOptions httpOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
        if(sslEnabled){
                httpOptions.setSsl(true);
                httpOptions.setKeyStoreOptions(sslKeyStoreOptions);
        }

        log.info("starting web server on port: " + port);
        vertx
                .createHttpServer(httpOptions)
                .requestHandler(router::accept).listen(
                port,
                result -> {
                    if (result.succeeded()) {
                        setStarted(true);
                        log.info("Server started and ready to accept requests");
                        fut.complete();
                    } else {
                        setStarted(false);
                        fut.fail(result.cause());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private void handleSocketOpenEvent(BridgeEvent be){
        String host =be.socket().remoteAddress().toString();
        String localAddress = be.socket().localAddress().toString();
        log.info("Socket connection opened! Host: " + host + " Local address: " + localAddress);
    }

    private void handleRegisterEvent(BridgeEvent be){
        String host =be.socket().remoteAddress().toString();
        String localAddress = be.socket().localAddress().toString();
        String address = be.getRawMessage().getString("address").trim();
        log.info("Eventbus register event! Address: " + address + " Host: " + host + " Local address: " + localAddress);
    }

    private void handleUnregisterEvent(BridgeEvent be){
        String host =be.socket().remoteAddress().toString();
        String localAddress = be.socket().localAddress().toString();
        String address = be.getRawMessage().getString("address").trim();
        log.info("Eventbus unregister event! Address: " + address + " Host: " + host + " Local address: " + localAddress);
    }

    private void handleSocketCloseEvent(BridgeEvent be){
        String host =be.socket().remoteAddress().toString();
        String localAddress = be.socket().localAddress().toString();
        log.info("Socket connection closed! Host: " + host + " Local address: " + localAddress);
    }

    //Method handles logging at custom level for access logging to files
    private void handleAccessLogging(RoutingContext routingContext){
        Marker accessMarker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("ACCESS");

        if(routingContext.normalisedPath().contains("/api")){
            log.info(accessMarker, "Api access log: request= " + routingContext.normalisedPath() + " source=" + routingContext.request().remoteAddress());
        }
        else{
            log.info(accessMarker, "Web access log: path= " + routingContext.normalisedPath() + " source= " + routingContext.request().remoteAddress());
        }

        routingContext.next();
    }

    /**
     * Accept a payload (anything) and publish to the provided destination
     *
     * @param routingContext
     */
    private void publish(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        String destination = routingContext.request().getParam("destination");
        String payload = routingContext.getBodyAsString();
        if ((destination == null) || (payload == null)) {
            Exception e = new Exception("Missing arguments");
            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(406);
            routingContext.fail(e);
        } else {
            log.info("API Call -> Publishing to destination: " + destination + " payload: " + payload);
            vertx.eventBus().publish(destination, payload);
            routingContext
                    .response()
                    .setStatusCode(200)
                    .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .end(payload);
        }
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    public void setStarted(boolean started) {
        this.started = started;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public Router getRouter(){
        if(router == null){
            router = Router.router(vertx);
        }
        return router;
    }

    public void setRouter(Router router){
        this.router = router;
    }

    public void setSslOptions(JksOptions keyStoreOptions, JksOptions trustStoreOptions) {
        this.sslKeyStoreOptions = keyStoreOptions;
        this.sslTrustStoreOptions = trustStoreOptions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your JS code that connect to WebSocket/EventBus?

Comment: I'm making a testing a simple example project, will update with code soon.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin added some code, let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can be resolved by doing the following:

1. In the Java verticle, move the Eventbus handler to the top, before any other handlers. I believe the BodyHandler or CorsHandler were messing it up and causing the 500 error.

   ```
   ...
   router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(sockJsHandler);
   ...
   // enable handling of body
   router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
   router.route().handler(corsHandler);
   router.route().handler(this::handleAccessLogging);

   // publish a payload to provided eventbus destination
   router.post("/api/eventbus/publish/:destination").handler(this::publish);
   ```